# Why does my DAO read a .txt file and not store all lines of data?

Tags: java, arraylist, dao

I am fairly new to Java and am currently working on a small application that can store and manipulate city data that is read from a text file. I have a DAOTextImpl class that is supposed to read from the text file, pick all the lines of data and store them in an ArrayList to be sorted. So far i can only get it to pick up 3 of the 4 lines of data it is mean to store.

Could someone take a look to see why only the first 2 sets of city data are being picked up and stored (2015 & 2016)?

Note: this is my first time using StackOverflow so if there is anything I've missed please let me know.

Code:

```
public class DaoTextImpl implements DAOInterface {

static final char DELIMITER=',';

@Override
public Repository load(String filename) {

    Repository repository = new Repository();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String[] temp;
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<YearData> yearData = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            lines.add(line);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            temp = lines.get(i).split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));
            if (temp.length == 4) {
                int id = Integer.valueOf(temp[0]);
                String cityName = stripQuotes(temp[1]);
                String country = stripQuotes(temp[2]);
                int noofyeardata = Integer.valueOf(3);

                for (int j = (i + 1); j < (i + noofyeardata); j++) {
                    String[] yearDataArray = lines.get(j).split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));
                    String year = stripQuotes(yearDataArray[0]);
                    float precipitation = Float.valueOf(yearDataArray[1]);
                    int maxtemp = Integer.valueOf(yearDataArray[2]);
                    int mintemp = Integer.valueOf(yearDataArray[3]);
                    int windspeed = Integer.valueOf(yearDataArray[4]);
                    String winddirection = stripQuotes(yearDataArray[5]);
                    yearData.add(new YearData(year, precipitation, maxtemp, mintemp, windspeed, winddirection));
                }
                repository.add(new City(id, cityName, country, yearData));
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return repository;
}
```

Text File contents:

```
1,"Cartagena","Spain",3
"2015",0.2,33,26,6,"S"
"2016",0.0,33,24,8,"SSW"
"2017",0.0,32,25,6,"E"
2,"Glasgow","Scotland",3
"2015",0.0,19,8,3,"SE"
"2016",0.1,21,11,6,"SE"
"2017",2.1,19,11,9,"SW"
3,"Valencia","Spain",4
"2015",0.0,34,24,6,"SE"
"2016",0.0,39,23,5,"SSE"
"2017",0.0,32,24,5,"E"
"2014",0.0,29,20,6,"ESE"
```

Comment: You are off by one - `j < (i + noofyeardata)` must be `j <=(i + noofyeardata)`

Comment: @user7 thanks for looking at this, i set the above and ran again, it works for the first 2 cities but for the Valencia set it does not pick up the 4th set of data. do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have expanded my earlier point and the other bug into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues in your code.

1) You are off by one in the condition check

`j < (i + noofyeardata)` must be `j <= (i + noofyeardata)`

2) `int noofyeardata = Integer.valueOf(3)` must be `int noofyeardata = Integer.valueOf(temp[3])`. That is why you always read `noofyeardata` as `3`

One more general point<sup>1</sup>. After you complete the inner loop, you need not continue the outer loop (`i` counter) from where you left off. You can increment `i` by `noofyeardata` (`i = i + noofyeardata + 1`) inside the *for* loop body (since you have already processed `noofyeardata` rows). With this you can also remove the *if (temp.length == 4)* check.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size();) {
        temp = lines.get(i).split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));
        int id = Integer.valueOf(temp[0]);
        String cityName = stripQuotes(temp[1]);
        String country = stripQuotes(temp[2]);
        int noofyeardata = Integer.valueOf(temp[3]);

        for (int j = (i + 1); j <= (i + noofyeardata); j++) {
           //your existing code
        }
        repository.add(new City(id, cityName, country, yearData));
        i += noofyeardata + 1;
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is assuming the contents of the file strictly follow the data format you have mentioned.

```
<id>, <cityName>, <country>, <noofyeardata1>
<noofyeardata1 rows>
<id>, <cityName>, <country>, <noofyeardata2>
<noofyeardata2 rows>
....
```

Comment: When implementing this I get the following error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""2017""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you remove the `i++` from the *for* loop?

Comment: Can you check if the file has the data in the expected format? If not, you cannot implement what I have mentioned in the last point